# Optimal use of the Luajit API

Tags: luajit

I'm developing a program which generates some Lua code and then runs it.

I can either (1) ask the program to generate a file so that I can use the command-line luajit compiler or (2) ask the program to directly run luajit through the API.

After some benchmarking it appears that method (1) is faster.
It makes me think that maybe I'm not using the API in an optimal way. I basically do a serie of dostring(chunk) and checks for errors.

So is there a good way of using the API when aiming at performance ?

Comment: as the api would only involve RAM access, while a temporary file involves disk IO, I'd expect the api to be significantly faster. the luajit executable also only uses the api, so I suspect you are missing some optimizations there. or the system's caches are helping you with the disk IO.